# Centering buttons programmatically in gamescene

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

I created a simple game in Sprite Kit with Swift and in the beginning of the game I created a `UIButton` that says "start" and after pressing it, will start the game. But the problem is that the button that I created is centered in the middle only for iPhone 6. When I run it on iPads or iPhone 6+, the start button changes place.

Is there a way to center it for all devices? I am able to do this for `UILabel`s by just doing `labelname.position.x = view!.center.x`. But for `UIButton`s, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
buttonName.center = self.view!.center
```

You may not need autolayout, but if you have to, try
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk)

Comment: i dont think its working. its not letting me do the buttonname.center. i think it said center cannot be implemented or something

Comment: just use autolayout, and add the constraints to center it. follow the video tutorial set for help

Comment: nevermind i got it to work! Thanks so much @Evo Sae 5! :)

Comment: @King_Cui what did you do to fix it? Maybe others might want to know.